# Should translations pay more attention to the antithetical parallelism of Prov. 3:34?

Tags: greek, hebrew, hebrew-bible, proverbs

> אִם־לַלֵּצִ֥ים‬
> הֽוּא־יָלִ֑יץ
> וְ֝לַעֲנָיִ֗ים‬
> יִתֶּן־חֵֽן׃
> (Prov. 3:34, MT)

Does it better fit the antithetical parallelism of the poetry of this verse to translate the verse:

> Although He will turn up his nose at the snob, He will give grace to the lowly/humble.

This is similar to how the Septuagint (LXX) translates the Hebrew.

> κύριος ὑπερηφάνοις [to the arrogant] ἀντιτάσσεται [He opposes], ταπεινοῖς δὲ δίδωσιν χάριν.
> (Prov. 3:34, LXX)

> ליץ: qal: pf. לַצְתָּ: **talk big, boast** Pr 9:12. †
> polel: pt. לֹצְצִים (w/o מ‍) as noun: mockers or rebels Ho 7:5. †
> **hif**.: pf. הֱלִיצֻנִי; impf. יָלִיץ; pt. מֵלִיץ, pl. cs. מְלִיצֵי, sf. מְלִיצַי, מְלִיצֶיךָ:—1. *mock, ridicule*: acc. pers. Ps 119:51, metaph. acc. *mock at* (justice) Pr 19:28, **make fun of** (God subj. le & obj.) **Pr 3:34**;—2. pt. mēlîṣ spokesman Is 43:27; Jb 33:23; 2 C 32:31; > interpreter (of foreign language) Gn 42:23. †
> hitpolal: impf. תִּתְלֹצָֽצוּ: give onesf. airs Is 28:22. †
> --
> Holladay, W. L., & Köhler, L. (2000). *A concise Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament* (p. 176). Leiden: Brill.

**The meaning is not always negative**  While context is negative, scoffer tends to imply scoffing God.  The antithetical implication is elevating oneself compared to the lowly.

> לִיץ S3887, 3945 TWOT1113 GK4329, 4372] vb. *scorn* (NH id.; vb. not in cognates; cf. Ph. מלץ **interpreter** CIS22.44.88; Arabic لَاصَ (lāṣa) is turn aside (intrans.); hence perhaps prop. **speak indirectly or obliquely**, Fl Pr 1, 6);—Qal Pf. 3 m. לַצְתָּ Pr 9:12; Impf. יָלִיץ 3:34 + 2 times; Pt. לֵץ 9:7 + 11 times; pl. לֵצִים ψ 1:1 + 3 times;—**scorn**, וְלַצְתָּ לְבַדְּךָ תִשָּׂא Pr 9:12 if thou **scornest** thou alone shalt bear it (opp. חָכַמְתָּ), c. acc. 14:9; 19:28; c. לְ, לַלֵּצִים הוּא־יָלִיץ **scorners** he (God) scorneth **3:34; הַלֵּץ the scorner is proud and haughty** 21:24, delights in **scorning** 1:22, is incapable of discipline 9:7, **reproof** 9:8; 15:12, or **rebuke** 13:1, cannot find wisdom 14:6; is an abomination 24:9, should be avoided ψ 1:1; smitten and punished for the benefit of the simple Pr 19:25; 21:11 and banished for the removal of contention 22:10; judgment is prepared for him 19:29; || עָרִיץ Is 29:20; wine is a scorner Pr 20:1.—**Hiph.** Pf. 3 mpl. sf. הֱלִיצֻנִי ψ 119:51; Pt. מֵלִיץ Gn 42:23 Jb 33:23; pl. cstr. מְלִיצֵי 2 Ch 32:31; sf. מְלִיצַי Jb 16:20; מְלִיצֶיךָ Is 43:27;— 1. **deride** Jb 16:20 ψ 119:51. 2. Pt. **interpreter** Gn 42:23 (E); fig. **of intermediaries between God and man**, Jb 33:23 Is 43:27; **ambassador** 2 Ch 32:31. Poʿlel; Pt. pl. לֹצֲצִים (םְ dropped Kö 479) **scorners** Ho 7:5. Hithpoʿl; Impf. תִּתְלוֹצָ֑צוּ **act as a scorner, shew oneself a mocker**, Is 28:22.
> --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). *Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon* (p. 539). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

> אִם (ʾim): pt.; ≡ Str 518; TWOT 111—**1.** LN 89.65–89.70 **if**, i.e., a marker of a condition, real or unreal, with or contrary to fact (Ge 4:7); **2.** LN 67.17–67.64 **whenever, as often as,** i.e., a marker of indefinite and multiple points of time (Ge 38:9); **3.** LN 89.65–89.70 **whether**, i.e., a marker of an indirect condition (Ecc 12:14); **4.** LN 89.71–89.75 **even though, although**, i.e., a marker of a concession (Jdg 13:16); **5.** LN 91.6–91.12 unit: אִם לֹא (ʾim lō(ʾ)) **surely, formally, if not**, i.e., a marker of emphasis in a discourse (1Ki 20:23); **6.** LN 89.65–89.70 unit: אִם (ʾim) … אִם (ʾim) **whether … or**, i.e., a multiple marker of condition (Ex 19:13); **7.** LN 89.65–89.70 **If?**, i.e., a marker of a question, introducing a condition, real or unreal (Ge 38:17), note: these categories are likely incomplete; see grammars and lexicons, esp. BDB
> --
> Swanson, J. (1997). Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains : Hebrew (Old Testament) (electronic ed.). Oak Harbor: Logos Research Systems, Inc.

Comment: Is not the key to translating this the initial אִם־ which usually introduces a conditional clause?

Comment: @Dottard you are correct that אם is usually a conditional, but here it seems to be emphasizing the opposite-parallelism that Perry Webb noted:  "Just as G-d will cause the scorners to be scored, He will cause the humble to be find grace."

Comment: @diyImma - Is that not what most translations broadly say?

Answer (score 1):

Prov. 3:34
Young's Literal Translation

> If the **scorners** He doth **scorn**, Yet to the humble He doth give grace.

mocks/scorns
לַלֵּצִ֥ים (lal·lê·ṣîm)
Preposition-l, Article | Verb - Qal - Participle - masculine plural
Strong's 3887: Ambassador, have in derision, interpreter, make a mock, mocker

those who mock/scorners
יָלִ֑יץ (yā·lîṣ)
Verb - Qal - Imperfect - third person masculine singular
Strong's 3887: Ambassador, have in derision, interpreter, make a mock, mocker

```
 אִם־    לַלֵּצִ֥ים‬   הֽוּא־     יָלִ֑יץ וְ֝לַעֲנָיִ֗ים‬ יִתֶּן־חֵֽן׃
            H3887        H3887
```

These two Hebrew words share the same lexeme. In LXX, they are different lexemes:

```
κύριος ὑπερηφάνοις    ἀντιτάσσεται, ταπεινοῖς δὲ δίδωσιν χάριν.
       G5244          G498
       the proud      rebuke
```

Should translations pay more attention to the antithetical parallelism of Prov. 3:34?

This is a matter of trade-off between antithetical parallelism and literal wording.

New International Version achieved a pretty balance:

```
He mocks              proud mockers              
but shows favor to    the humble and oppressed.
```